# How to set a multiple item selection drop-down list to work only in a certain range's

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

this script allows you to choose more data in one cell
separated by a comma

but now it works in the whole sheet
how to modify it to work only in these ranges only?
(['B3:U27'], ['W3:AP27'])

what i tried is i saw on dev google
[setActiveRangeList(rangeList)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setactiverangelistrangelist)

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['B3:U27', 'W3:AP27']);
sheet.setActiveRangeList(rangeList);
```

but it did nothing just select(highlight) these ranges B3:U27, W3:AP27

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if (activeCell.getColumn() > 1) {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;

    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");

    } else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
        
      } else {
        if (newValue.indexOf(oldValue) < 0) {
          activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);

        } else {
          activeCell.setValue(newValue);

        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Please ask a real question. Provide all the details required to answer the question.  What are you trying to what does your data look like and how do you want it to change.

Comment: Multiple Dependent Dropdowns:https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find if `e.range` is within one of the ranges you listed, and return early from the `onEdit()` if it is not. Try this:

```
/**
* Appends the text string entered in a magic cell to the previous contents in the cell.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  const magicCells = ['Sheet1!B3:U27', 'Sheet1!W3:AP27'];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let intersect;
  if (e.value === undefined
    || !e.oldValue
    || !magicCells.some(rangeA1 => (intersect = getRangeIntersection_(e.range, ss.getRange(rangeA1))))) {
    return;
  }
  let update = e.oldValue;
  if (String(e.oldValue).indexOf(e.value) === -1) {
    update += ', ' + e.value;
  }
  intersect.range.setValue(update);
}

/**
* Returns the intersection of two ranges as an object that contains the sheet,
* a new range, and the range's grid coordinates and dimensions.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} range A spreadsheet range object.
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} intersectingRange A spreadsheet range object that possibly overlaps range.
* @return {Object} The intersection of range and intersectingRange, or null if they do not overlap. The return object has these fields:
*                  sheet       The sheet of range.
*                  range       The cells common to range and intersectingRange.
*                  rowStart    The first row of the intersection.
*                  columnStart The first column of the intersection.
*                  rowEnd      The last row of the intersection.
*                  columnEnd   The last column of the intersection.
*                  numRows     The number of rows in the intersection.
*                  numColumns  The number of columns in the intersection.
*/
function getRangeIntersection_(range, intersectingRange) {
  // version 1.4, written by --Hyde, 19 October 2020
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetId() !== intersectingRange.getSheet().getSheetId()) {
    return null;
  }
  var rowStart = Math.max(range.getRow(), intersectingRange.getRow());
  var rowEnd = Math.min(range.getLastRow(), intersectingRange.getLastRow());
  if (rowStart > rowEnd) {
    return null;
  }
  var columnStart = Math.max(range.getColumn(), intersectingRange.getColumn());
  var columnEnd = Math.min(range.getLastColumn(), intersectingRange.getLastColumn());
  if (columnStart > columnEnd) {
    return null;
  }
  return {
    sheet: sheet,
    range: sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, rowEnd - rowStart + 1, columnEnd - columnStart + 1),
    rowStart: rowStart,
    columnStart: columnStart,
    rowEnd: rowEnd,
    columnEnd: columnEnd,
    numRows: rowEnd - rowStart + 1,
    numColumns: columnEnd - columnStart + 1,
  };
}
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but looking at the script here is everything new to me 
all I understand is that you separate into sheets, which worked in the whole spreadsheet before, but I think I can "fix it" with this line
const rangesA1 = ['B3:U27', 'W3:AP27'];

Sorry everyone, i didn't even think that two ranges would make it necessary to change the whole script!
I thought it was just a few lines..
anyone who understands the script will know where to paste mine 
sorry, but I have no idea

Comment: I am guessing that you want the script to appends a text string entered in a magic cell to the previous contents in the cell. Edited the script in the answer to make it fully functional, based on what I think you may be after.

Comment: ohh yess, you are the best!!
thanks for including it in your script.
I mark your answer to solved!
I would like to ask one more thing that was useful in "my" script 
when i select an item in the cell then another one
I can manually write text in same cell without duplicating everything 
if I swap these two e.oldValue e.value to e.value e.oldValue  it does not duplicate but it also deletes what I manually write in
if (String(e.value).indexOf(e.oldValue) === -1)
do you have any idea how to "activate" it to accept the manually typed text after the selected item/item's?

Comment: That's a different question. Please post it separately.